# how to skip sql timestamp to get records for specific date

Tags: sql

I want to compare the date in my sql query and get the records for a specific date, but it is stored in timestamp format in postgres.
What kind of query could compare only date parts, since I want and skip the time part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Query will give you date like '2012/11/22' which you can use for date comparison.

```
 SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),111)
 //OR simply
 select CAST(GETDATE() as DATE)
```

You can see more formats here :- [CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

Comment: Note that this is SqlServer code and the OP asked about Postgresql.

Comment: Previously it was tagged as only SQL

Comment: I added the tag postgresql because OP's wrote `format in postgres`. Now I removed the tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tab 
where date_col::DATE BETWEEN '2012-01-01'::DATE AND '2012-01-05'::DATE
```

### [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/ae750/2/0) DEMO